# How to create new jira issue after jenkins run jobs

Tags: jenkins, jira, jira-plugin

I want to create a new Jira issue after everytime Jenkins jobs running no matter the result is passed or failed. But my setting was no effect in Jenkins. It only created a Jira issue for the first time, then, it only added a comment to the old JIRA issue after running job finished.

Here is my setting:

["JIRA: Create issue" in Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6iCh.png)

[Only updated JIRA Comments in the old Jira issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAjNm.png)

BTW: Other related functions are OK. Like： triggered Jenkins job after Jira issue status changed or added comments to jira after running job.

```
Versions:

Jenkins ver. 2.32.2

JIRA plugin: 2.5 

JIRA Integration for Jenkins: 3.1.3

Jira Issue Updater: 1.18

JIRA Pipeline Steps: 1.3.1

JiraTestResultReporter plugin 2.0.6

JIRA Trigger Plugin: 0.5.1

jira-ext Plugin:0.7

JIRA: 7.5.0
```

Thanks in advance!